# Deal with virtualhost activation trouble

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, dns-hosting, http-status-code-403

Can't have any error log in my apache server.

For example, I have a 403 forbidden error when accessing a page with this conf :

```
Alias /nconf /usr/local/nconf/
<Directory "/usr/local/nconf">
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Options
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 10.1.1.0/8
</Directory>
```

I use several virtualhost and when i deactivate it, it will work normally. But when i activate it, 403 forbidden.

Is the virtualhost a problem for website using the default apache server ? Is there a way to deal with ? (accessing to default server by ip, and virtualhost to deal with dns)

Comment: I''m a bit lost here, what is the actual question? You want to know why apache is not loging errors on `error_log`, why you are getting an error when accessing the website or what?

Comment: I've modified the title because i've modified the question by writing it

Comment: Still don't understand what you need. You say `Can't have any error log in my apache server.` and a bit later... `I have a 403 forbidden error when accessing a page with this conf`. So, are you saying that there's nothing on `error_log` when it should be an `error 403` or are you saying that you cannot access the website with that virtualhost?

Comment: In fact, the two fact is correct. When i activate virtualhost, it will redirect the default server to a 403 forbiddent and there will be no log in the default error_log. When it's not, everithing is good

Comment: Alright, then, the forbidden error is probably because of permissions or because of the directive `Allow from 10.1.1.0/8`, make sure you are connecting from there. Not sure why isn't it being logged in `error_log` unless you have it configured to another path.

Comment: Have you trried this?. Order deny,allow Deny from All    Allow from 10.1.1.0/8. If it's still not fixing it, then it's an issue with directory permissions